I cant review the App in the meta for developers - Not ending process of App Review
I have problem with reviewing the App with Facebook login.
We use Laravel with Sanctum to log-in users (backend service).
I can't review the app, because they always want us to confirm that "At the time of review, we are unable to find your Website, WE can see that it was deleted from your end. Could you please confirm whether it was deleted accidentally or intentionally."
When we confirm that, we get the same message over and over again.
We use Facebook login only in Android App and iOS app, we don't have option to login on our landing page, also we provided meta information in App Settings > Basic about platforms which uses facebook login option (iOS and Android) like package names, class name bundle id and iphone store id with links to the google and android stores to download it.
Someone have idea what we doing wrong?

Do you have the "Website" platform configured in your app settings?

@C3roe if you mean in "App Settings > Basic" i have only IOS and Android platform.  When they (meta) suggest me, to add "website" i get message, that they can't find login option on my website (it's only landing page)
